# python - best way to stack matrices

Tags: python, numpy

i have two matrices

```
[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0]]

[[1,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,1,1]]
```

I would like them v-stacked and h-stacked like this

```
[[0,0,0,1,1,1],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0]]
```

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`np.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy-block) for this:

```
A = np.array([[0,0,0],
              [0,0,0],
              [0,0,0]])

B = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [1,1,1],
              [1,1,1]])

np.block([[A, B], [B, A]])
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```